# How to get expected string in linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to delete all line except the string that are with in the character "[ ]".
Input file: ODBC.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

odbcname     = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN
[odbcname]

Driver       = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description  = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN
[Default]
```

Expected Output : ODBC.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

[odbcname]

[Default]
```

Also need to different dsn names after deleting this old one.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `grep "\[.*\]" input.txt`

Comment: `Also need to different dsn names after deleting this old one` - no idea what that means...

Comment: Jean-François Fabre   i  need answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39726811/4087559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` with in place (`-i`) edit:

```
sed -Ei '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/ !d' ODBC.ini
```

- `\[[^]]*\]` matches the lines that have `[]`
- `^[[:blank:]]*$` matches blank lines or lines containing only whitespaces
- `!d` removes the unmatched lines

Similarly, printing only the matched lines in `awk`:

```
awk '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/' ODBC.ini
```

Recent GNU `awk` has in place editing option:

```
awk -i inplace '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/' ODBC.ini
```

POSIX-ly:

```
awk '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/' ODBC.ini >ODBC_temp.ini && mv ODBC{_temp,}.ini
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -E '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/ !d' file.txt
[ODBC Data Sources]

[odbcname]

[Default]


$ awk '/\[[^]]*\]|^[[:blank:]]*$/' file.txt
[ODBC Data Sources]

[odbcname]

[Default]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time heemayl

Comment: Could you please explain the pattern " \[[^]]*\] " how it works.

Comment: @subakhank Sure. In `\[[^]]*\]`, `\[` matches literal `[`, `[^]]*` matches zero or more characters upto next `]`, `\]` matches literal `]`.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ grep '\[' file
[ODBC Data Sources]
[odbcname]
[Default]
```

then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Sorry Ed that is my mistake . "I want to clear old DSN config files and want to add new DSN config files".From ur ans it will clear after that i need to add new config file in the same pattern with out disturbing the content of [ ].

Comment: looking for answer  stackoverflow.com/q/39726811/4087559

Comment: had you posted a clickable link i might've looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

Print the line starting with `[` and *everything  after that till* *first* `]` is reached.

```
 grep -oP '^\[.*?]' infile 
    [ODBC Data Sources]
    [odbcname]
    [Default]
```

using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[|]' '/^\[/{print $1}' infile
[ODBC Data Sources]
[odbcname]
[Default]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`. The following `awk` program matches either lines containing a `[value in brackets]` or empty lines.

```
awk '/^\[.*]$/ || /^$/' file
```

Output:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

[odbcname]

[Default]
```